# Java: how to create and run class structure?

Tags: java, oop, extend

I have to create following class hierarchy.

[image]

I started this way:

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
  private int credits;
  public Student(String name, int credits) {
    this.name = name;
    this.credits = credits;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  // ...the same for "credits"...

  public String toString(){
    return "name: "+this.name+", credits: "+this.credits;
  }

  public void print(){
    System.out.print(this.toString);
  }
}

public class DailyStudent extends Student {
  private int scholarship;
  public DenniStudent(int scholarship) {
    this.scholarship = scholarship;
  }

  public int getScholarship(){
    return scholarship;
  }
  public void setScholarship(int scholarship) {
    this.scholarship = scholarship;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return "Scholarship: "+scholarship;
  }
}
```

The class called **RemoteStudent** will look almost the same as the class **DailyStudent**.

Now I have to create the class **StudentTest**, where I will test what I just created. In this class I should create the instances (objects) from each class above with using declared constructor (with all arguments). On all created objects I should apply the methods **toString()** and **print()**.

But here I am facing the problem - I don't know, how to set up the class **StudentTest** and how to create there all needed instances... and how to use there the method **print()**, if this method is only int the **Student** class.

I am total Java newbie, but, are two 2 first methods correct?

Thank you guys for your help and patience.

**EDIT:** implementation of the **StudentTest** method:

```
public class StudentTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DailyStudent daily = new DailyStudent(1000);
    daily.print(); // this is what I mean
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you buy a book on basic Java programming concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks fine. Is that what you want `toString` to return though? Also, take a look at abstraction, unless your professor hasn't talked about that yet. Maybe they will introduce this topic. As you can see the `toString()` method is used in all 3 classes. And you have a class hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jane, I'll do. But the problem that I am solving now - how can I apply to all instances the method **print()** and **toString()**, if the method print is only in the **Student** class?

Comment: Check out the edit above. This is what you are looking for. Depending on what IDE you are using... it will give you the option to automatically bring those methods in with a single click. Then you can change those methods up in your RemoteStudent class and it will "Override" the method from Student. Take a look at Abstraction examples on youtube or search within google.

Comment: Jane, please, take a look at the updated OP. I am not sure, if we are talking about the same. I created a **StudentTest** class, where I am trying to print out the data from the **DailyStudent** class. I don't know, if I can do it that way, or if I need to use there the identificator `super`. This makes me confused.

Comment: Ya actually that should work. Have you ran that main method? It should grab 'this' instance which will be daily and use it's toString method. This is the "override".

Comment: I would check out 'Head first java' and skim through the sections that you think are important. You can easily get the .pdf version for free as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve problmes one-by-one.

1. To create instances use Factory pattern. Create class `StudentFactory` that will have method `createStudent()` with all needed arguments and create either remote or daily student according on these arguements. The use it as following:

   Student student = StudentFactory.create(......);

From now you can use Student and no-one outside factory knows which student is it.

1. You can use your `print` method now: `student.print()`. It will work for both remote and daily students.
2. Use factory in your test. If it is JUnit based test you can use annotation `@RunWith(Parametrized.class)` and write only one test case that will run for both daily and remote students.

   @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
   public class StudentTest {
       private Student student;

   ```
   public StudentTest(Student student) {
       this.student = student;
   }

   @Parameter
   public static Collection<Student> createStudent() {
       return  Arrays.asList(
                   StudentFactory.create(....),    // create remote student
                   StudentFactory.create(....));   // create daily student
   }
   // write your tests here
   ```

   }

This test case will run for both students created in `createStudent()` method.